# What is the purpose of test_files configuration in a gemspec

Tags: rubygems

The [RubyGems Specification Reference](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) says:

> A collection of unit test files. They will be loaded as unit tests when the user requests a gem to be unit tested.

However there is no `gem test` command, and unlike the `files` config which is used in the packaging, I don't see any obvious place this is used.  Google also seems not to turn up anything.

Is there any point for specifying `test_files` in a gem?

Answer (score 22):

I've been trying to find an answer to this as well, and while I haven't turned up a definitive "don't use test_files" it seems that support has been somewhat deprecated.

From what I can tell, the answer to your question is "it depends".  There are some points to specifying test_files, but they might not be what you expect/want:

1. From a test perspective, rubygems doesn't seem to do anything as far as running the test files specified.
2. From a packaging standpoint, they will be installed, which may or may not be useful for an end user.

Some references:

- An open [Issue #735](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/735) to not install test_files, deferred to a post-2.x RubyGems release due to 'backward compatibility'
- [Commit 429f88...](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/429f883210f8b2b38ea310f7fc6636cd0e456d5c) in the RubyGems github repo, which removed code that tests gems (included back in v1.5.0)
- A closed [Bug #27507](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/429f883210f8b2b38ea310f7fc6636cd0e456d5c) to remove -t from gem install (it was removed after some discussion included in the bug)