# What are the practical advantages of using `add_development_dependency` in .gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

..vs just listing gems used for the gem development in Gemfile (while everyone uses bundler anyway)..

..except for giving your fingers extra work?

Comment: I guess development dependencies could be in the Gemfile, but anything the gem depends on will need to be in the gemspec. It's better to not lock gem dependencies to versions, which is what happens in Gemfile.lock

Comment: @maxple the question is about `add_development_dependency` and doesn't mention `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: You're talking about using the Gemfile. Which produces a Gemfile.lock. Anyway, gems require a gemspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear there is any.

In theory, `RubyGems` has the information necessary to run tests with `add_development_dependency` and `test_files` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871541/what-is-the-purpose-of-test-files-configuration-in-a-gemspec)).

Some believe that this should be outside the scope of `RubyGems` (see [this huge thread](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1104)).

In practice, there is currently no real advantage, and the fact that `RubyGems` still installs test files by default is a drawback, as might be the lack of flexibility that `Gemfile` offers.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of `add_development_dependency` is that if you publish your Gem to rubygems.org, those dependencies can be listed on the gem's details page.  Thus if anyone finds your gem via rubygems.org, they have an idea right away what will be required if they want to contribute to the gem.